# Multiple Groovy classes in one file when running as a script

Tags: groovy

I have a project with multiple groovy files, and I have several "tiny" classes that I want to put in a single file.

Basically, here is what I want:

Foo.groovy:

```
class Foo
{
    Foo() { println "Foo" }
}
```

Bar.groovy:

```
class Bar
{
    Bar() { println "Bar" }
}

class Baz
{
    Baz() { println "Baz" }
}
```

script.groovy:

```
#!/groovy/current/bin/groovy

new Foo()
new Bar()
new Baz()
```

And then:

```
$ groovy ./script.groovy 
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
/home/tmp/script.groovy: 5: unable to resolve class Baz 
 @ line 5, column 1.
   new Baz()
   ^

1 error
```

Any idea?

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine for me. I've prepared the repo with your classes and no problem at all: https://github.com/mkordas/groovy-classes-in-one-file

Comment: I cloned your repo, and still:
    MacBook:groovy $ groovy script.groovy 
    org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
    /groovy-classes-in-one-file/src/main/groovy/script.groovy: 5: unable to resolve class Baz 
     @ line 5, column 1.
       new Baz()
       ^
    1 error

Comment: Actually it works with Gradle/IntelliJ, but indeed from commandline without compilation it doesn't work. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When Groovy is run as a script without compilation, then classes are resolved by matching names to a corresponding `*.groovy` source files, so only classes where the class name matches the source filename can be found.

This is [known problem](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-3793) marked as Not a Bug.

As a workaround you can compile classes first with `groovyc` and then run using `java`:

```
groovyc *
java -cp '/some/path/groovy-2.4.3/lib/groovy-2.4.3.jar;.' script
Foo
Bar
Baz
```

Comment: hasn't it resolved yet? When i trying to comple it returns same error:
PS C:\Program Files\Java\groovy-2.4.18\bin> .\groovyc.bat E:\groovy\*
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
E:\groovy\GlobalVars.groovy: 1: Invalid duplicate class definition of class GlobalVars : The source E:\groovy\GlobalVars.groovy contains at least two definitions of the class GlobalVars.
One of the classes is an explicit generated class using the class statement, the other is a class generated from the script body based on the file name. Solutions are to change the file...

Answer (score 0):

Well, you haven't really explained why you would want to do this, so perhaps the obvious answer won't help you, but you can just do this:

```
#! env groovy
class Foo
{
Foo() { println "Foo" }
}

class Bar
{
Bar() { println "Bar" }
}

class Baz
{
Baz() { println "Baz" }
}

new Foo()
new Bar()
new Baz()
```

Comment: Thxs for your answer. Well, obviously I do *not* want only 1 big file that contains all my classes. What I want is an entry file (script.groovy) and several files that contain 1 or more classes. 'hope this is clearer

Comment: To whomever downvoted this: it's really obnoxious to do that without commenting.